# Imagen por defecto nginx

Tags: nginx

Tengo puesta esta regla en nginx que me muestra una imagen por defecto si no encuentra la imagen necesaria:

```
location ~*  \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico) {
        expires 30d;
        error_page 404 /imagen/logo.png;
        }
```

Hasta aquí todo genial. El tema es que cuando inspecciono la página sigo viendo los errores 404 de las imágenes que no encuentra. ¿Es posible hacer que esos errores no se muestren si se están sustituyendo por una imagen por defecto?

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Esa directiva location esta haciendo referencia a todo el sitio web, lo que podrías hacer es especificar un "root" que apunte del directorio donde tengas las imágenes, sino durante la navegación vas a ver ese error_page por todo tu sitio web.

Comment: Hola, luis13cst, podrías también dar un ejemplo de como hacerlo para que al usuario le quede más claro. Saludos.